# Scrapy ahora timesout con un sitio web que solía funcionar bien

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, permisos, scrapy

Estoy usando scrapy para scrapear un sitio web: `https://www.sephora.fr/marques/de-a-a-z/`.
Hace un año funcionaba bien, pero ahora muestra un error:

> El tiempo de espera del usuario causó un fallo de conexión: La obtención de https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt tardó más de 180.0 segundos

Se reintenta durante 5 veces y luego falla por completo. Puedo acceder a la url en chrome pero no funciona en scrapy. He intentado usar agentes de usuario personalizados y emular las peticiones de cabecera pero sigue sin funcionar.

Un amigo mío ejecutó mi código sin siquiera cambiar lo de los robots y no me salió el tiempo de espera. Como he contrarrestado bloques con proxies y etc y como generalmente es el camino a seguir pero parece que el problema no está en mi código sino en mi entorno. Pero no se que parte de ahí ....

Abajo está mi código:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import json
import requests
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlencode
import re
from ..pipelines import Pipeline


class SephoraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    The SephoraSpider object gets you the data on all products hosted on sephora.fr
    """

    name = 'sephora'
    allowed_domains = ['sephora.fr']
    # the url of all the brands
    start_urls = ['https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/']
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': '180',
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://www.sephora.fr'


    def parse(self, response):
        """
        Parses the response of a webpage we are given when we start crawling the first webpage.
        This method is automatically launched by Scrapy when crawling.
        :param response: the response from the webpage triggered by a get query while crawling.
        A Response object represents an HTTP response, which is usually downloaded (by the Downloader)
        and fed to the Spiders for processing.
        :return: the results of parse_brand().
        :rtype: scrapy.Request()
        """

        # if we are given an url of the brand we are interested in (burberry) we send an http request to them
        if response.url == "https://www.sephora.fr/marques/de-a-a-z/burberry-burb/":
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_brand)
        # otherwise it means we are visiting another html object (another brand, a higher level url ...)
        # we call the url back with another method
        else:
            self.log("parse: I just visited: " + response.url)
            urls = response.css('a.sub-category-link::attr(href)').extract()
            if urls:
                for url in urls:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url + url, callback=self.parse_brand)

    ...
```

Scrapy log:

```
(scr_env) antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/bass2/scraper (master) $ scrapy crawl sephora
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43) - [GCC 8.4.0], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-1068-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': '180',
 'EDITOR': '',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: af81c5b648cc3542
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-13 16:40:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:41:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:42:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:42:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:42:19 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py:276: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Passing a 'spider' argument to ExecutionEngine.download is deprecated
  return self.download(result, spider) if isinstance(result, Request) else result

2022-03-13 16:43:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 360, in _cb_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(f"Getting {url} took longer than {timeout} seconds.")
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:49:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:50:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:51:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:51:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:52:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:53:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:54:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:54:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 2 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:55:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:56:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1657, in _inlineCallbacks
    cast(Failure, result).throwExceptionIntoGenerator, gen
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 62, in run
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 360, in _cb_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(f"Getting {url} took longer than {timeout} seconds.")
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1881,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1080.231435,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 16, 57, 19, 904633),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 28,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 72749056,
 'memusage/startup': 70950912,
 'retry/count': 4,
 'retry/max_reached': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 4,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError'>": 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 16, 39, 19, 673198)}
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Voy a revisar los headers de la petición usando fiddler y corriendo algunas pruebas. ¿Tal vez Scrapy está enviando un header `Connection: close` por defecto, lo que haría que no reciba respuesta del sitio sephora?

Aquí están los logs cuando elijo no respetar el archivo robots.txt:

```
(scr_env) antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/bass2/scraper (master) $ scrapy crawl sephora
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43) - [GCC 8.4.0], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-1068-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': '180',
 'EDITOR': '',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3f4205a34aff02c5
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-13 23:24:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:25:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:26:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:26:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:27:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:28:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:29:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:29:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 2 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:30:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:31:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:32:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:32:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:32:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1657, in _inlineCallbacks
    cast(Failure, result).throwExceptionIntoGenerator, gen
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 62, in run
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 360, in _cb_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(f"Getting {url} took longer than {timeout} seconds.")
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:32:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-13 23:32:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 951,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 540.224149,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 23, 32, 39, 59500),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 19,
 'memusage/max': 72196096,
 'memusage/startup': 70766592,
 'retry/count': 2,
 'retry/max_reached': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 23, 23, 38, 835351)}
2022-03-13 23:32:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Y aquí está la salida de la `pip lista` en mi entorno:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\scrapy-scraper>pip list
Package             Version
------------------- ------------------
async-generator     1.10
attrs               21.4.0
Automat             20.2.0
beautifulsoup4      4.10.0
blis                0.7.5
bs4                 0.0.1
catalogue           2.0.6
certifi             2021.10.8
cffi                1.15.0
charset-normalizer  2.0.12
click               8.0.4
colorama            0.4.4
configparser        5.2.0
constantly          15.1.0
crayons             0.4.0
cryptography        36.0.1
cssselect           1.1.0
cymem               2.0.6
DAWG-Python         0.7.2
docopt              0.6.2
en-core-web-sm      3.2.0
et-xmlfile          1.1.0
geographiclib       1.52
geopy               2.2.0
h11                 0.13.0
h2                  3.2.0
hpack               3.0.0
hyperframe          5.2.0
hyperlink           21.0.0
idna                3.3
incremental         21.3.0
itemadapter         0.4.0
itemloaders         1.0.4
Jinja2              3.0.3
jmespath            0.10.0
langcodes           3.3.0
libretranslatepy    2.1.1
lxml                4.8.0
MarkupSafe          2.1.0
murmurhash          1.0.6
numpy               1.22.2
openpyxl            3.0.9
outcome             1.1.0
packaging           21.3
pandas              1.4.1
parsel              1.6.0
pathy               0.6.1
pip                 22.0.4
preshed             3.0.6
priority            1.3.0
Protego             0.2.1
pyaes               1.6.1
pyasn1              0.4.8
pyasn1-modules      0.2.8
pycparser           2.21
pydantic            1.8.2
PyDispatcher        2.0.5
pymongo             3.11.0
pymorphy2           0.9.1
pymorphy2-dicts-ru  2.4.417127.4579844
pyOpenSSL           22.0.0
pyparsing           3.0.7
PySocks             1.7.1
python-dateutil     2.8.2
pytz                2021.3
queuelib            1.6.2
requests            2.27.1
rsa                 4.8
ru-core-news-md     3.2.0
Scrapy              2.5.1
selenium            4.1.2
service-identity    21.1.0
setuptools          56.0.0
six                 1.16.0
smart-open          5.2.1
sniffio             1.2.0
sortedcontainers    2.4.0
soupsieve           2.3.1
spacy               3.2.2
spacy-legacy        3.0.9
spacy-loggers       1.0.1
srsly               2.4.2
Telethon            1.24.0
thinc               8.0.13
tqdm                4.62.3
translate           3.6.1
trio                0.20.0
trio-websocket      0.9.2
Twisted             22.1.0
twisted-iocpsupport 1.0.2
typer               0.4.0
typing_extensions   4.1.1
urllib3             1.26.8
w3lib               1.22.0
wasabi              0.9.0
webdriver-manager   3.5.3
wsproto             1.0.0
zope.interface      5.4.0
```

Con `scrapy runspider sephora.py` observo que no acepta mi importación relativa `from ..pipelines import Pipeline`:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\scrapy-scraper\nosetime_scraper\spiders>scrapy runspider sephora.py
2022-03-14 01:00:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-03-14 01:00:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.
9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform
 Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2022-03-14 01:00:27 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: Unable to load 'sephora.py': attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Aqui estan los `settings.py`:

```
# Scrapy settings for nosetime_scraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'nosetime_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['nosetime_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'nosetime_scraper.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1


# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 7
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = True

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'nosetime_scraper.middlewares.NosetimeScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'nosetime_scraper.middlewares.NosetimeScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'nosetime_scraper.pipelines.NosetimeScraperPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```